# xpath->query() return 0 even element id present on the source

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to find an element using @$xpath->query()  function but it return a zero length for some of the url. Here's my code what I m trying to do :

```
$strLink ="http://www.pennenergy.com/3bl-energy-news.html"

$arrElements = array('//div[@id="threeblmediawidget"]', '//div[@id="threeblmediadetaillist"]');

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$fileContents = file_get_contents($strLink);

@$dom->loadHTML($fileContents);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($arrElements as $strKey => $strVal) {
   $arrParams[] = @$xpath->query($strVal);
}
```

That code working fine for most the url except some of them. Those url have one of the id element on the source but it returns zero. I am not able to find the issue.

I have tried to use xpath checker plugin in Mozilla and it shows the result for those url but not with the code I using. if someone have any suggestion, please help.

Comment: Attempts to answer without the xml/html document(s) would be just wild guessing.

Comment: @VolkerK for the security concern I am not able to share actual url you can take any of the url and apply to that code.

Comment: @VolkerK I have update my question with actual url where I am having issue.

Comment: Seems the markup is too messed up to parse properly. The ID is definitely in there, it's just not reachable by typical DOM methods.

Comment: If you remove the HTML 4.01 strict doctype it works - the document is just not valid and this doctype disables some of the "guessing modes" of the parser.

Comment: @VolkerK Ya may be that will be a problem with it, but I have no access actually it's a third party website which uses our code. I have no access to that website, Is there any way to resolve this issue without doing any thing to that site?

Comment: @VolkerK I can understand that if this site has HTML 4.01 strict method but i have another url (http://www.trcri.com/index.php?page=corporate-social-responsibility-news) which creating the same issue but having the  XHTML 1.0 doctype.

Comment: That link works fine for me, the second DOMNodeList has one item.

Comment: @VolkerK Strange even it's working in my side as well now, Any solution I can apply for site who uses a strict HTMl 4.01?

Comment: Yes, write them, rant, call them, rant again, ask for the boss of whoever answered the phone and get the page fixed. In the meantime you could just str_replace() the doctype declaration or maybe run it through tidyhtml - but it will come back to bite you sooner or later, probably sooner.